# iPhone: core data update data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am using core data in my app , wants to know how to update the entity data and its relation.

Here 'Feature' is the entity and 'Alias' is the `NSSet` relation.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Features" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


NSManagedObjectContext *aliasMOC = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Alias" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Using `insertNewObject` creates a new set and only its connections are changed whereas the old `NSSet` remains as it is in sqlite, which i believe will increase the 'unnecessary data' without links to a Feature entity in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what you are attempting to do here, but `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` does not return an `NSManagedObjectContext`.  You typically use the same ManagedObjectContext for all your database operations.  You probably need to go through a [tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php) before continuing.

I think you are trying to create a to-many relationship, in which case you can create a child entity and then specify its parent, something like this (untested):

```
Parent *parent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
Child *child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

child.parent = parent;
```

`parent.children` should now contain `child`.  This assumes that `Child` and `Parent` entities exist in your model and as objects and have relationships set up.